# Как изменить запись в БД используя Django ORM одним запросом

Tags: python, sql, база-данных, django, orm

Мне нужно изменить только один элемент в модели django. Какой метод QuerySet может позволить изменить один элемент без предварительного получения объекта ORM через objects.get (Просто нужно сделать чтобы код работал как можно быстрее). Запрос из SQL примерно `UPDATE table SET variable='value' WHERE other_variable=0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сделать изменение без вычитывания объекта одним модифицирующим запросом к базе можно используя метод `update`:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(other_variable=0).update(variable='value')
```

Иногда бывает нужно использовать значение(я) из записи, которую изменяем. Это можно сделать используя [query expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/expressions/):

```
MyModel.objects.filter(other_variable=0).update(variable=F('variable') + 1)
```

Это будет аналог такого SQL запроса:

```
UPDATE table SET variable=variable+1 WHERE other_variable=0
```

Если в условии фильтра используется поле с внешним ключом, например так:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(user=user).update(variable='value')
```

то при этом все равно выполняется один запрос:

```
UPDATE my_model SET "variable" = 'value' WHERE "my_model"."user_id" = 3
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'Profile' object has no attribute 'update'

Comment: А если использовать only, то ForeignKey всегда будет загружатся? К примеру если objects.only('variable').get(user=user), то ORM не подаст дополнительный запрос на получение user, ведь user не указан в only?

Comment: objects.only('variable').get(user=user) при таком варианте будет второй запрос на user, который ForeignKey, если да, то как указать user в only, просто user?

Comment: Мне нужно только одно поле (к примеру variable), но нужно найти где user = other_variable. В данном случае user это ForeignKey. Нужно ли указывать поле ForeignKey в only или ForeignKey всегда запраливается. Просто неоч хочется, чтобы было несколько запросов в одном действии

Comment: В этом случае все равно будет выполнен только один запрос. Дополнил ответ.

Comment: На всякий уточню. То есть не нужно в only дополнительно писать поле с ForeignKey?

Comment: Вам вообще не нужно использовать `only`. Я в ответе написал, как сделать модифицирующий запрос, который не будет читать данные (это именно то, о чем изначальный вопрос) и какие именно SQL запросы будут выполнены для соответсвующих команд django. Я не совсем понимаю, почему вас интересует `only` в контексте этого вопроса.